# CSS border within 2 arrows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a border within 2 arrows(left and right).

Screenshot -- [image]

There is a line between 2 arrows.

```css
.carousel-controls {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.carousel-controls span.next {
  background: url(https://s10.postimg.org/hdeqo479l/snext.png) no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 10px;
}

.carousel-controls span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.carousel-controls span.prev {
  background: url(https://s16.postimg.org/dx0m87tud/prev.png) no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 45px;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-controls">
  <span class="prev"></span>
  <span class="next"></span>
</div>
```

The line draws from the top of the arrows and extends till to the height of the span. Please let me know if this is possible.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.carousel-controls {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.carousel-controls span {
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
  height: 45px;
}

.carousel-controls span.next {
  background: url(https://s10.postimg.org/hdeqo479l/snext.png) no-repeat 100% 50%;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.carousel-controls span.prev {
  background: url(https://s16.postimg.org/dx0m87tud/prev.png) no-repeat 0% 50%;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-controls">
  <span class="prev"></span>
  <span class="next"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Didn't think about background position. Nice one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgwBQN?editors=1100)

```
.carousel-controls span.next {
  background: url(https://s10.postimg.org/hdeqo479l/snext.png) no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  background-position: 0 50%;
}

.carousel-controls span.prev {
  background: url(https://s10.postimg.org/hdeqo479l/snext.png) no- repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 45px;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  background-position: 0 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you want to centre two block elements with a sufficient amount of padding and then just add a border to one of them.

```css
.carousel-controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-controls span {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 16px;
}

.carousel-controls span.next {
  background-image: url(https://s10.postimg.org/hdeqo479l/snext.png);
  border-left: 1px solid #666;
  left: 50%;
}

.carousel-controls span.prev {
  background-image: url(https://s16.postimg.org/dx0m87tud/prev.png);
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-controls">
  <span class="prev"></span>
  <span class="next"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **border-right** property in `.prev` class, and `margin-right` value would be same like `padding-right` to center border between arrows

> `margin-right: 3rem; 
>   border-right: 1px solid #000;`

```css
.carousel-controls {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.carousel-controls span.next {
  background: url(https://s10.postimg.org/hdeqo479l/snext.png) no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 10px;
}

.carousel-controls span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.carousel-controls span.prev {
  width: 16px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-right: 3rem;
  padding-right: 3rem;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-controls">
  <span class="prev">&#8592;</span>
  <span class="next">&#8594;</span>
</div>
```